# How to make a page responsive for all device sizes using bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a beginner so I have copied lots of my code from Bootstrap.
My page is responsive for some devices, but for 1024px screen size it's not very responsive. Can someone help me fix my CSS code, please?

I know it requires a little fix inside a `@media` query in CSS but I could not make it. I really need some help, please.

```css
HTML,
body,
header,
.view {
  height: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 740px) {
  html,
  body,
  header,
  .view {
    height: 1000px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 850px) {
  html,
  body,
  header,
  .view {
    height: 600px;
  }
}

.btn .fa {
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.top-nav-collapse {
  background-color: #424f95 !important;
}

.navbar:not(.top-nav-collapse) {
  background: transparent !important;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar:not(.top-nav-collapse) {
    background: #424f95 !important;
  }
}

.btn-white {
  color: black !important;
}

h6 {
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.rgba-gradient {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(42, 27, 161, 0.7), rgba(29, 210, 177, 0.7) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(42, 27, 161, 0.7), rgba(29, 210, 177, 0.7) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 45deg, from(rgba(42, 27, 161, 0.7)), to(rgba(29, 210, 177, 0.7)));
  background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(42, 27, 161, 0.7), rgba(29, 210, 177, 0.7) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to 45deg, rgba(42, 27, 161, 0.7), rgba(29, 210, 177, 0.7) 100%);
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.bg {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("assets/imgs/beach-enjoyment-exercise-1390403.jpg");
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}

.row h3 {
  color: rgb(199, 197, 197);
  font-size: 15px;
}

.row h1 {
  color: rgb(102, 100, 100);
  font-size: 30px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .row {
    display: grid;
    width: 700px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-top: 60px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row {
    display: grid;
    width: 700px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top: 60px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .callout-wrap,
  .vertical_photo {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .banner-left,
  .banner-right,
  .content-left-side,
  .content-right-side {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .border_drop_bg {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .vertical_photo {
    display: none;
  }
}

.row {
  background-color: rgb(232, 232, 236);
  padding: 30px;
  margin-left: 20x;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container a {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.container img {
  width: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-left: 85%;
}

.row p {
  color: rgb(98, 95, 95);
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.mySlides {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <!--slides-->
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <!--slides-->
</header>

<main>
  <!--slides-->
  <div class="container-for-two-row-ellements">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h1>Podologie • Posturologie</h1>
        <h3>— Pierre-Marie HAUDRY</h3>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible</a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="card card-body">Lorem ipsum dolor
                  <br> sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                  <br/> sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
                  <br/> dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                  et d
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Exercitation</a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="card card-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem
                  ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem
                  ipsum dolor sit amet, con sed d sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Consectetu</a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="card card-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse4">dolore</a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="card card-body">is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse5"> ullamco</a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="card card-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem
                ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum
                dolor sit amet, con sed d sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
          <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/imgs/img1.jpg" alt="First slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/imgs/img2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/imgs/img3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/imgs/img4.jpg" alt="Third slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/imgs/img5.jpg" alt="Third slide">
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--slides-->
</main>

<footer></footer>
```

Comment: You had a *bunch* of duplicate libraries linked in there, including ***5** different* versions of jQuery

Comment: I think you would benefit from reading on how to actually use bootstrap to make a page responsive.

Comment: yes you are right. honestly I copied and pasted lots off them

Answer (score 1):

You setup your responsive grid by your classes.

**Class prefixes:** `.col-`, `.col-sm-`, `.col-md-`, `.col-lg-`, `.col-xl-`.

Info about the [Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="bg-primary col-xs-6 col-sm-3">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-3</div>
  <div class="bg-secondary col-xs-6 col-sm-3">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-3</div>
  <div class="bg-success col-xs-6 col-sm-3">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-3</div>
  <div class="bg-danger col-xs-6 col-sm-3">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MzweblksjdfksnfkjoifskyCode Run the snippet and make your screen smaller and you will see changes in the grid. Do not forget to load the cdn of bootstrap: https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 0):

You need to red about the Grids, the "powerfull" feature from Bootstrap
[Grids Layouts](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

A DIV fully "responsive" will be like that:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
```